# How to run a function and change the content every 5 seconds on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, jsx, use-effect

Hello i am wondering how can u guys run a function on every 5 seconds on React js

Here's the code:

```
function Home() {

const [quotes,setQuotes] = useState([])

const getQuotes = ()=>{
    axios.get('https://api.kanye.rest')
    .then(res=>{
        const quotes = res.data.quote
        setQuotes(quotes)
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getQuotes()
},[])


return (
    <div className="home-container">
        <p className="pcolor">Here's a random quotes from Kanye:</p>
        <p>{quotes}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

I am wondering how can u get the data every 5 seconds, so i it will automatically update in the jsx.
And yeah, the kanye api are giving us a random quote everytime we request it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of JSON structure the quote is, you might have to target it differently than I did, but this just randomly picks a quote every 5 seconds from the state and console.logs() it. Since it looks like you fetch all quotes at once and save them to the state, you can just do this with the client.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState([
    {quote: "test1", id: "1"},
    {quote: "test2", id: "2"},
  ])

  const runFunc = (quote) => {
    console.log(quote)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      runFunc(quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length) + 1  ])
    }, 5000);
  },[])


  return (


    <div></div>
  );
}
```

This actually might work better :)

```js
function Home() {

const [quotes,setQuotes] = useState([])
const [currentQuote,setCurrentQuote] = useState({
quote: "",
id: ""
})


const getQuotes = ()=>{
    axios.get('https://api.kanye.rest')
    .then(res=>{
        const quotes = res.data.quote
        setQuotes(quotes)
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getQuotes()
    quotes && setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentQuote({
      quote: quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length) + 1  ].quote
      id: quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length) + 1  ].id
      })
    }, 5000)
},[quotes])


return (
    <div className="home-container">
        <p className="pcolor">Here's a random quotes from Kanye:</p>
        <p>{currentQuote && currentQuote}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

If you wanted to request it directly:

(im not sure how your quote api works, if you can just add the index into the req header then you can just target it directly.)

```js
function Home() {

const [currentQuote, setCurrentQuote] = useState({
 quote: "",
 id: ""
})

const getQuotes = ()=>{ //i pick a random quote from 1 to 100 and set it
    axios.get(`https://api.kanye.rest/${[[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1  ]]}`) //targetting specific index quote
    .then(res=>{
        const quote = res.data.quote
        setCurrentQuote({quote: quote.quote, id: quote.id})
    }, 5000);
        ])
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
    setInterval(() => {
      getQuotes() //i get ran every 5 seconds
    }, 5000)
},[])


return (
    <div className="home-container">
        <p className="pcolor">Here's a random quotes from Kanye:</p>
        <p>{currentQuote.quote}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

If you api works with Ids:

```js
    function Home() {

    const [currentQuote, setCurrentQuote] = useState({
     quote: "",
     id: ""
    })

    const getQuotes = (quoteId)=>{ //i pick a random quote from 1 to 100 and set it
        axios.get(`https://api.kanye.rest/`, {quoteId}) //targetting specific index quote
        .then(res=>{
            const quote = res.data.quote
            setCurrentQuote({quote: quote.quote, id: quote.id})
        }, 5000);
            ])
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setInterval(() => {
          getQuotes("youridhere123abc") //i get ran every 5 seconds
        }, 5000)
    },[])


    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            <p className="pcolor">Here's a random quotes from Kanye:</p>
            <p>{currentQuote.quote}</p>
        </div>
    )}
```

Comment: I feel like a dumb person, i tottally forgot about the setInterval. Thanks, it works! and i just need to set the first useEffect dependencies to '[]' but without setInterval. And after the first render i set the second useEffect's dependencies to [quotes] and use the setInterval. Thanks!

Comment: wait, it actually better to do it with ur code.

Comment: @AlifGarindra Let me know if you still have questions :)

Comment: You'll need to `clearInterval` otherwise that will continue to run even when this component is unmounted.

Comment: @RossAllen ah yeah thanks! i also forgot to clear the interval and the response goes crazy

Comment: @RossAllen can you show me how to clear the interval?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Use a ref to keep track of a stateful value that doesn't affect rendering,
// the `setInterval` ID in this case.
const intervalRef = useRef();
const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const getQuotes = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.kanye.rest')
    .then(res=>{
        const quotes = res.data.quote
        setQuotes(quotes)
    })
  }

  intervalRef.current = setInterval(getQuotes, 5000);

  // Clear the interval when this hook/component unmounts so it doesn't keep
  // running when this component is gone.
  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Ah so if im unmounting this component and rendering another component, the function will keep running by himself? So we need to clear the interval? if that so, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, you must return a function from `useEffect`. The cleanup function gets called whenever the `useEffect` does and when the component unmounts.